# change options of select tag according to another

Tags: jquery, ajax

this is my jqyery code in this i am calling a api and getting some employees id now i want to change options of my employees names according to those ids and remove all other basically i want only those names whose ids match with those ids

```js
<script>


$(document).ready(function(){

$('#project_name').on('change', function() {
//  var values;
var item=$('#project_name :selected').val();
alert(item);
$.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
   url: 'http://localhost/programs/new/api/Project/get_employees_to_assinged_project?project_id='+item, //replace the plus by a comma
   success: function (data) {
      $.each(data, function(key,value){
    console.log(value.project_employee_id);
// //
// $("#employees_name option").filter('#'+value.project_employee_id,function() {
//     // return this.text == text1;
//  });
      });
            }
              });

});
});
</script>
```

```html
 <form method="get">
                    <button value="" name="datefilter" type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="daterange-btn">
                      <span>May 25, 2017 - June 7, 2017</span>
                      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                    </button>
                    <select id="project_name" name="project_name" style="width:200px;" class="">
                      <option value="">No project</option>

                                        <option value="1">api</option>
                                      <option value="2">new project</option>
                                      <option value="3">new project2</option>
                  
                  </select>
                  <select name="employees_name" style="width:200px;" class="">
                    <option value="">No Employee</option>

                                    <option value="1">Administrator</option>
                                  <option value="2">sunitshakya</option>
                                  <option value="3">shikshasingh</option>
                                  <option value="255">abhishekshukla</option>
                
                </select>

                    <input type="hidden" name="start" id="start" value="">
                    <input type="hidden" name="end" id="end" value="">

                    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit">
                 </form>
```

```js
<script>


$(document).ready(function(){

$('#project_name').on('change', function() {
//  var values;
var item=$('#project_name :selected').val();
alert(item);
$.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
   url: 'http://localhost/programs/new/api/Project/get_employees_to_assinged_project?project_id='+item, //replace the plus by a comma
   success: function (data) {
      $.each(data, function(key,value){
    console.log(value.project_employee_id);
// //
// $("#employees_name option").filter('#'+value.project_employee_id,function() {
//     // return this.text == text1;
//  });
      });
            }
              });

});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Why is this tagged as `php`?

Comment: do u have a php problem?

Comment: no i have problem in jquery

Comment: i think you want dependent dropdown.  Search for it first. and there is no php so remove php tag

Comment: Why you want to match ? It can be done by just removing all previous options from dropdown and add new list come through ajax request

Answer (score 0):

You have an error when getting the value of your select. Try with this code and check if it works now. The ID should be transmitted successfully. When you get errors then you have some issues in your API:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#project_name').on('change', function() {
//  var values;
var item=$('#project_name').val();
alert(item);
$.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
   url: 'http://localhost/programs/new/api/Project/get_employees_to_assinged_project?project_id='+item, //replace the plus by a comma
   success: function (data) {
      $.each(data, function(key,value){
    console.log(value.project_employee_id);
// //
// $("#employees_name option").filter('#'+value.project_employee_id,function() {
//     // return this.text == text1;
//  });
      });
            }
              });

});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="get">
                    <button value="" name="datefilter" type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="daterange-btn">
                      <span>May 25, 2017 - June 7, 2017</span>
                      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                    </button>
                    <select id="project_name" name="project_name" style="width:200px;" class="">
                      <option value="">No project</option>

                                        <option value="1">api</option>
                                      <option value="2">new project</option>
                                      <option value="3">new project2</option>
                  
                  </select>
                  <select name="employees_name" style="width:200px;" class="">
                    <option value="">No Employee</option>

                                    <option value="1">Administrator</option>
                                  <option value="2">sunitshakya</option>
                                  <option value="3">shikshasingh</option>
                                  <option value="255">abhishekshukla</option>
                
                </select>

                    <input type="hidden" name="start" id="start" value="">
                    <input type="hidden" name="end" id="end" value="">

                    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit">
                 </form>
```